# loadingwrapper getting fadeout before completing the functionality

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC web application, below jquery function will upload the file and shows the file in grid. While uploading, I'm displaying one loading wrapper (acts as progressbar). Its working fine but sometimes loadingwrapper is getting fade out before the file gets loaded into grid. 
Please let me know how to show loadwrapper till the file gets uploaded and refresh in grid.

View:

```
    <div id="loadingwrapper">
    <div id="loadingcontent">
        <p id="loadingspinner">
            <img src="~/Images/load-indicator.gif" />
        </p>
    </div>
```

Script:

```
  $("#lnkAddAttachment").click(function (e) {

        oFiles = document.getElementById("txtFile").files[0];
        nFiles = oFiles.size;

        var selectedFile = document.getElementById("txtFile").files[0];

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var fd = new FormData();
        var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "ESignature/getFile";
        fd.append("file", document.getElementById('txtFile').files[0]);

        $("#loadingwrapper").fadeIn();

        xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        xhr.send(fd);
        xhr.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
        }, false);
        var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "ESignature/Registration";

        $('#gridAttachments').load(url + ' #gridAttachments', function () {
                        $("#loadingwrapper").fadeOut();
                    });

            return false; 
    });
```

Comment: Side-note: Don't inject MVC values direct into your Javascript. For things like the site root `@Url.Contemt("~/")` just store that once in a global var that can be used by all scripts. Debugging Javascript works a lot better in separate files (which don't allow injection).

Comment: Re your basic problem: You seem to be doing the file upload and the grid attachments load in parallel so you have no control over whether the upload finishes before or after the load. If you need to wait for both before fading in, use `Deferred` promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved code related to refreshing grid to EventListener of xhr and it worked.
As soon as file upload gets finished, addEventListener of Load will execute.
Below link is helpful
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Thank you, TrueBlueAussie for your continuous support

```
 xhr.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
 var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "ESignature/Registration";
 $('#gridAttachments').load(url + ' #gridAttachments');
                $("#loadingwrapper").fadeOut();
 }, false);
```

Comment: You never mentioned you could upload then download. I had assumed from your code you needed to do both at once for a reason. My Bad

Comment: Oh. After uploading a file, I'm showing file details in grid. There are two options to download and Delete

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Still I'm surprised why deferred is not working